# How to bind multiple events with .live in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an input text with two events and dinamically I clone it several times. To bind this elements correctly I use:

**NOTE: This input text has the focusin and focusout events.**

```
$('[selector_input]').die().live( 'focusin', function() {
       alert( 'You focused me' );
});

$('[selector_input]').die().live( 'focusout', function() {
       alert( 'Bye!' );
});
```

The final result is that all inputs only executes: focusout event. If I don't use .die(), I will get repeated call the same events.

Now the solution could be:

```
$('[selector_input]').die().live( 'focusout focusin', function(event) {
    if (event.type == "focusin")
       alert( 'You focused me' );
    else
       alert( 'Bye!' );
});
```

But I like and independence like the first code.

Comment: You do realize that the point of `.die()` is to remove any event handlers that were previously set for that selector, right?

Comment: yes I now, but I don't understand why when i quit the .die(), I get multiple events attached, for example: Without .die(), I get 5 alerts('You focused me') what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have to rebind events at all? Live (in opposite to bind) is meant to bind events to selector once and for all, i.e. event is bound to elements matching the selector even if they are added after the binding.

Comment: @Cris: Keep in mind that an alert box becomes the foreground thing, causing the previously focused thing to unfocus.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the event type for the call to `die()`

```
$('[selector_input]').die('focusin').live( 'focusin', function() {
   alert( 'You focused me' );
});

$('[selector_input]').die('focusout').live( 'focusout', function() {
   alert( 'Bye!' );
});
```

I'm not quite sure why you need the `die()` call though, are you binding the events repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$('path to your input').live({
    focusin: function() { $('some output div').html('Focus!'); },
    focusout: function() { $('some output div').html('Bye!'); }
});
```

or you could just remove the `.die()` -- its very purpose is to remove the previous event handlers for that selector.

If you're playing with alert boxes, i wouldn't mess with focus events at the same time -- the alert box becomes the active thingie when it appears, causing focused stuff to unfocus (and then possibly refocus), and causing your event handler to get called sometimes infinitely.

BTW, see http://jsfiddle.net/9pjWa/ for an example of how to use `.live()` -- it sounds like you're doing it wrong.  The *very point* of `.live()` is that you do not need to re-bind the events every time you add an element; the event handler is on the *document*, not the elements, and each element that matches the selector can trigger the event whether they were added before or after `.live()`.  In fact, every time you re-bind, you add another event handler that handles *all* of the matching elements, which is another reason why you're seeing the event handler called a bunch of times.

Comment: 5 lives --> you will get: 5 !!Focus! Focus! Focus! Focus! Focus!

Comment: What in the hell are you doing calling the same thing 5 times?  Do you even understand how `.live()` works?

Comment: jajajajjaaj... Not only five times, six, four, etc. When I add more NEW DOM with jQuery, the LIVE event is called.. you know that?

Comment: Try removing this code at all after cloning your elements, this should work. You don't have to rebind live events.

Comment: Shouldn't be.  If the new box is a clone of the old one, thus having the same type and CSS classes, you should not need to call `live()` to re-hook-up events.  That's its very purpose.